# selected inside options tag in shiny

Tags: html, r

Is there a way to put selected attribute inside option.

```
asd <- c()
for (i in c("a","b")){
asd <- tagList(asd,tagList(tags$option(value = i, paste0("selected>", i))))
}

asd
<option value="a">selected&gt;a</option>
<option value="b">selected&gt;b</option>
```

Expected output

```
asd
<option value="a" selected>a</option>
<option value="b" selected>b</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create selected elements, use

```
asd <- c()
for (i in c("a","b")){
  asd <- tagList(asd,tagList(tags$option(value = i, i, selected="selected")))
}
```

This returns

```
<option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
<option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>
```

which is equivalent to just

```
<option value="a" selected>a</option>
<option value="b" selected>b</option>
```

in pretty much every browser.